# Batch: How to remove all empty columns from a csv file

Tags: batch-file

I have a CSV file like this:

> ```
> P,PC,,PL,B,15feb16,P,Bay,RP,15-FEB-16,22-FEB-16,7,,,,,,11,14,138,14,16,993.42,-12,-84,-12,,,,,,,,,17,2,-10,0,0,1,1,16:05:53,15FEB16 
> P,PC,,PL,I,1FEB-16,P,In,RP,15-FEB-16,22-FEB-16,7,,,,,,25,5,32,5,5,-29.7,-24,-168,-24,,,,,,,,,520,14,-10,0,0,1,1,10-MAY-201606:05:53,15-FEB-16 
> P,PC,,PC,S,15FEB16,P,Su,RP,15-FEB-16,22-FEB-16,7,,,,,,6,5,32,56,5,4.65,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,546,0,0,0,0,1,1,10-MAY-201606:05:53,15-FEB-16
> ```

The code I have written is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (C:\Pca.csv) do   (
    set line=%%a
    set line=!line:,,=, ,!
    set line=!line:,,=, ,!
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=," %%i in (^"!line!^") do (
        echo %%i,%%l>>C:\P.csv
    )
)
```

But it only deletes 2nd and 3rd column, no matter whether it is empty or contains data.

The sample output file should be like:

> ```
> P,PC,PL,B,15feb16,P,Bay,RP,15-FEB-16,22-FEB-16,7,11,14,138,14,16,993.42,-12,-84,-12,17,2,-10,0,0,1,1,16:05:53,15FEB16 
> P,PC,PL,I,1FEB-16,P,In,RP,15-FEB-16,22-FEB-16,7,25,5,32,5,5,-29.7,-24,-168,-24,520,14,-10,0,0,1,1,10-MAY-201606:05:53,15-FEB-16 
> P,PC,PC,S,15FEB16,P,Su,RP,15-FEB-16,22-FEB-16,7,6,5,32,56,5,4.65,0,0,0,546,0,0,0,0,1,1,10-MAY-201606:05:53,15-FEB-16
> ```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What are you expecting?

Comment: This code only delete 2nd and 3rd column, no matter whether it is empty or contains data @CSchulz

Comment: How is your `csv` delimited? By commas, as your code suggests or by spaces or tabs, how your example shows?

Comment: @Stephan its comma delimited

Comment: could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37300040/edit) your question to reflect that?

Comment: Is it possible in your CSV files that there is a column that contains data in some rows and no data in other rows? I mean something like this: row 1 contains `a,b,c`, row 2 contains `d,,f`;

Comment: @aschipfl No there is no such rows in my csv..

Comment: ...as Stephan already requested: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37300040/edit) your question and state the actual content of the sample file (when opened by a text editor like Notepad) rather than showing non-realistic space-separated data; otherwise it is quite hard to help you...

Comment: @aschipfl I have edited the question based on ur request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quite comprehensive and adaptive script that removes empty columns from CSV-formatted data.

---

Before the code is shown, let us take a look at the help message that appears when called with `/?`:

> ```
> "del-empty-cols-from-csv.bat"
>
> This script removes any empty columns from CSV-formatted data. A column is con-
> sidered as empty if the related fields in all rows are empty, unless the switch
> /H is given, in which case the first line (so the header) is evaluated only.
> Notice that fields containing white-spaces only are not considered as empty.
>
>
> USAGE:
>
>   del-empty-cols-from-csv.bat [/?] [/H] csv_in [csv_out]
>
>     /?      displays this help message;
>     /H      specifies to regard the header only, that is the very first row,
>             to determine which columns are considered as empty; if NOT given,
>             the whole data, hence all rows, are taken into account instead;
>     csv_in  CSV data file to process, that is, to remove empty columns of;
>             these data must be correctly formatted CSV data, using the comma as
>             separator and the quotation mark as text delimiter; regard that
>             literal quotation marks must be doubled; there are some additional
>             restrictions: the data must not contain any line-breaks; neither
>             must they contain any asterisks nor question marks;
>     csv_out CSV data file to write the return data to; this must not be equal
>             to csv_in; note that an already existing file will be overwritten
>             without prompt; if not given, the data is displayed on the console;
> ```

---

As you can read, there are two operation modes: standard (no switch) and header mode (switch `/H`).

Given that the following CSV data is fed into the script...:

> ```
> A, ,C, ,E,F
> 1, , ,4,5, 
> 1, , , ,5, 
> 1, ,3,4, ,
> ```

...the returned CSV data in standard mode will look like...:

> ```
> A,C, ,E,F
> 1, ,4,5, 
> 1, , ,5, 
> 1,3,4, ,
> ```

...and the returned CSV data in header mode (`/H`) will look like:

> ```
> A,C,E,F
> 1, ,5, 
> 1, ,5, 
> 1,3, ,
> ```

Remind that the spaces in the above sample data must actually **not** be present in the files; they have just been inserted here for better illustration of the said operation modes.

---

Now, this is the complete code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "OPT_HEAD=%~1"
if "%OPT_HEAD%"=="/?" (
    goto :MSG_HELP
) else if /I "%OPT_HEAD%"=="/H" (
    shift
) else if "%OPT_HEAD:~,1%"=="/" (
    set "OPT_HEAD="
    shift
) else set "OPT_HEAD="

set "CSV_IN=%~1"
if not defined CSV_IN (
    >&2 echo ERROR:  no input file specified!
    exit /B 1
)
set "CSV_OUT=%~2"
if not defined CSV_OUT set "CSV_OUT=con"

for /F "delims==" %%V in ('2^> nul set CELL[') do set "%%V="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not defined OPT_HEAD (
    for /F %%C in ('^< "!CSV_IN!" find /C /V ""') do set "NUM=%%C"
) else set /A NUM=1
set /A LIMIT=0
< "!CSV_IN!" (
    for /L %%L in (1,1,%NUM%) do (
        set /P "LINE="
        call :PROCESS LINE LINE || exit /B !ErrorLevel!
        set /A COUNT=0
        for %%C in (!LINE!) do (
            set /A COUNT+=1
            if not defined CELL[!COUNT!] set "CELL[!COUNT!]=%%~C"
            if !LIMIT! LSS !COUNT! set /A LIMIT=COUNT
        )
    )
)
set "PAD=" & for /L %%I in (2,1,!LIMIT!) do set "PAD=!PAD!,"
> "!CSV_OUT!" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!CSV_IN!") do (
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=%%L%PAD%"
        set "ROW="
        set /A COUNT=0
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        call :PROCESS LINE LINE || exit /B !ErrorLevel!
        for %%C in (!LINE!) do (
            endlocal
            set "CELL=%%C"
            set /A COUNT+=1
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if !COUNT! LEQ !LIMIT! (
                if defined CELL[!COUNT!] (
                    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%R in ("!ROW!,!CELL!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "ROW=%%R"
                    )
                ) else (
                    endlocal
                )
            ) else (
                endlocal
            )


            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        if defined ROW set "ROW=!ROW:~1!"
        call :RESTORE ROW ROW || exit /B !ErrorLevel!
        echo(!ROW!
        endlocal
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  var_return  var_string
set "STRING=!%~2!"
if defined STRING (
    set "STRING="!STRING:,=","!""
    if not "!STRING!"=="!STRING:**=!" goto :ERR_CHAR
    if not "!STRING!"=="!STRING:*?=!" goto :ERR_CHAR
)
set "%~1=!STRING!"
exit /B


:RESTORE  var_return  var_string
set "STRING=!%~2!"
if "!STRING:~,1!"==^""" set "STRING=!STRING:~1!"
if "!STRING:~-1!"==""^" set "STRING=!STRING:~,-1!"
if defined STRING (
    set "STRING=!STRING:","=,!"
)
set "%~1=!STRING!"
exit /B


:ERR_CHAR
endlocal
>&2 echo ERROR:  `*` and `?` are not allowed!
exit /B 1


:MSG_HELP
echo(
echo("%~nx0"
echo(
echo(This script removes any empty columns from CSV-formatted data. A column is con-
echo(sidered as empty if the related fields in all rows are empty, unless the switch
echo(/H is given, in which case the first line ^(so the header^) is evaluated only.
echo(Notice that fields containing white-spaces only are not considered as empty.
echo(
echo(
echo(USAGE:
echo(
echo(  %~nx0 [/?] [/H] csv_in [csv_out]
echo(
echo(    /?      displays this help message;
echo(    /H      specifies to regard the header only, that is the very first row,
echo(            to determine which columns are considered as empty; if NOT given,
echo(            the whole data, hence all rows, are taken into account instead;
echo(    csv_in  CSV data file to process, that is, to remove empty columns of;
echo(            these data must be correctly formatted CSV data, using the comma as
echo(            separator and the quotation mark as text delimiter; regard that
echo(            literal quotation marks must be doubled; there are some additional
echo(            restrictions: the data must not contain any line-breaks; neither
echo(            must they contain any asterisks nor question marks;
echo(    csv_out CSV data file to write the return data to; this must not be equal
echo(            to csv_in; note that an already existing file will be overwritten
echo(            without prompt; if not given, the data is displayed on the console;
echo(
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming, your original `csv` looks like this:

```
id_users,,,quantity,,date
1,,,1,,2013
1,,,1,,2013
2,,,1,,2013
```

then this single line should solve your request:

```
(for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (c:\pca.csv) do echo %%a,%%b,%%c)>c:\p.csv
```

resulting in:

```
id_users,quantity,date
1,1,2013
1,1,2013
2,1,2013
```

The trick is: consecutive delimiters are treated as one.

Edit: another approach, as it turned out, there are much more colums, than the original question showed.

```
@echo off
break>out.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (c:\pca.csv) do call :shorten "%%a"
goto :eof

:shorten
  set "line=%~1"
:remove
  set "line=%line:,,=,%"
  echo %line%|find ",,">nul && goto :remove
  echo %line%>>c:\p.csv
```

`break>c:\p.csv`: create outputfile (overwrite if exist)
replace two consecutive commas with one;
repeat, if there are any more consecutive commas.
Write the resulting line to the outfile.

Comment: Well - if you don't show us your real `csv`, we have to guess. In a comment you claimed, it's comma separated, so I used a comma separated file with emty columns.Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37300040/edit) your question with (a part of) your actual csv file  (Don't copy it from an excel sheet, but open it in notepad or `type c:\Pca.csv` and copy it from the cmd-box.)

Comment: few data are confidential so i couldnt share. Totally 43 columns were there.. and the columns which are empty were.(3,13,14,15,16,17,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34)

Comment: @Gowtham.S See my edit. It's essential to give us as much information as possible about your problem and your original data. As you can see, it strongly influences how to solve it. You can't expect a good working answer with a bad question with missing essential information.